# Ошибка в setInterval

Tags: javascript

По идее в конце должно выходить сообщение **все** и интервал кончается.

Интервал кончается, а сообщения нет.

Где ошибка?

```js
let timer = setInterval(() => alert('opa'), 500);

setTimeout(function() {
return clearInterval(timer);
alert('все'); 
},1500);
```

Comment: return прерывает выполнение функции, и до строчки с alert'ом дело не доходит

Comment: return надо поставить после alert?

Comment: return здесь вообще не нужен

Comment: А что надо?
Не могли бы вы показать наглядный пример?

Comment: Просто слово return уберите и всё

Comment: можно заменить `;` на `,`

Comment: @Grundy при этом return можно оставить?
Просто вверху человек сказал, что return надо убрать.

Comment: @Grundy зачем ?

Comment: @Black_Viper, да, return можно оставить

Comment: @andreymal, чтобы получить верное поведение :)

Comment: @Grundy с простым удалением return оно тоже будет верное, не надо новичков зазря путать

Answer (score 2):

```js
let timer = setInterval(() => alert('opa'), 500);

setTimeout(() => {
  clearInterval(timer);
  alert('все');
}, 1500);
```